# Code for decrypting simple sentences made with CodeBlocks crashes without outputting a single character

Tags: c++

I am making a program that inputs the alphabetical order for encrypting a sentence to decrypt it (just replacing characters). I am required to input the number of words it has, but the method I'm using doesn't need that so I just input it and do nothing with it (it doesn't matter because an AI will be verifying only the output of the program). I think I came up with a decent algorithm, but the program keeps crashing after I enter the encrypted sentence. I tried changing a lot of things but nothing seems to solve the issue. Also, I'm sorry for any things that don't make sense in the code, I'm just a beginner. Please help me stop the program from crashing so I can submit it before the end of tomorrow.

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i, j;
    string key, encrypted;
    cin >> key;
    char alphabet[]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    cin >> n;
    getline(cin>>ws, encrypted);
    for (i=0;i<=encrypted.size();i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<encrypted.size();j++)
        {
            if (encrypted[i]==key[j])
            {
                cout << alphabet[j];
            }
            else if (encrypted[i]==key[j]+32)
            {
                cout << alphabet[j]+32;
            }
            else if (encrypted[i]==' ')
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify the exact input that you use that causes the program to crash.

Comment: J should go from 0 to key size, not message size

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel   the decryption "key" I'm using is just the alphabet backwards and the encrypted message is supposed to be saying "The Sky Is Blue" but it's not working

Comment: @Jeffrey I tried replacing encrypted.size() with key.size() and it's now not crashing but the results are really weird. The output is something like T104101 B102108117101 and other stuff

Comment: You still did not specify the exact input. Your program takes 3 items of input, but you only specified 2.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzle   yes I said that I'm also required to input the number of words from the user, but my method doesn't need the number of words so I just input it and do nothing with it. The one I'm talking about is the integer n (the second input). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: sima sandouk, Post your code here.

Comment: The reason your question was closed was probably because you did not specify in the question which input is required in order to reproduce the issue. Instead, you only specified this in the comments section. Therefore, I suggest that you [edit] your question to include this important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has the following bugs:

### First bug:

As already pointed out in the comments section, you should change the line

`for (j=0;j<encrypted.size();j++)`

to

`for (j=0;j<key.size();j++)`

### Second bug:

Due to [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_promotions), the expression `alphabet[j]+32;` will evaluate to a value of type `int`, not `char`. This means that

`cout << alphabet[j]+32;`

will print a number, not a character. Therefore, you must cast the result of the expression back to the data type `char`, like this:

`cout << static_cast<char>( alphabet[j]+32 );`

### Third bug:

The line

`cout << " ";`

should only be called once per outer loop iteration, i.e. once per character in the string `encrypted`. However, you are calling it once per inner loop iteration, which means you are calling it several times per character. Therefore, you should remove that statement from the inner loop and put it into the outer loop.

### Fourth bug:

The line

`for (i=0;i<=encrypted.size();i++)`

is wrong. It should be `<` instead of `<=`. Otherwise, you will also process the terminating null character of the string, which is not meaningful.